# Anchor ToolStripProgressBar to right of StatusBar(StatusStrip)

Tags: winforms, toolstrip

I have a form with a statusbar that has 2 `ToolStripStatusLabel`s followed by a `ToolStripProgressBar`. I want the **progressbar** to be always **anchored to the right of the statusbar** - so when the window is resized/maximized, it should **automatically move**/repaint.

I thought this would be as simple as setting the 1st (left aligned) `ToolStripStatusLabel`'s `Spring` property to true, so when the form is resized/increased in size, and there is more space available, the 1st `ToolStripStatusLabel` would fill up that space and automatically push the `ToolStripProgressBar` to the Right.

But not only does that not do what I want - the 1st `ToolStripStatusLabel` actually **covers up** both the 2nd `StatusLabel` and the `ProgressBar`, basically occupying the whole statusbar. 
None of the ToolStrip controls have Anchor or even a MinSize.

SO how do I :

1. Anchor the `ToolStripProgressBar` to right of StatusBar(StatusStrip)
2. Mix some **fixed size** items (e.g the `ToolStripStatusLabel2` and `ToolStripProgressBar`) with a variably sized `ToolStripStatusLabel1` that grows when there is extra space?

Thanks in advance for your time and help !

~IM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all who may be interested.. Anchor property is available, although in Code only (not in designer) ...but in any case, it DOES NOT work.. I left a BUG in Connect and got the generic WillNotFix with the Message seeming to indicate they'll consider it only for a major revision.

For some reason the "Spring" property seems to be erratic.. In my ultra-simpistic examples it is working, but in some others where I do some custom painting (but in Child Forms in a MDIPArent, with the latter having ht eStatusBar) it is not. In those cases, there's still a simple workaround though - in the ReSize event of the MDIParent Form (that has the statusbar) change the size of the StatusLabel to make it bigger in the same proprtion as th width-change, so it pushes the ProgressBar to the right edge of the StatusBar

Answer (score 17):

There's a simple solution. Make one fake ToolStripStatusLabel, empty the .Text and set .Spring = true;

After that, add your ToolStripProgressBar. Make sure the order is label first, then progressbar.

Answer (score 12):

1. Set the StatusStrip, LayoutStyle property to HorizontalStackWithOverflow.
2. Set the control Alignment to Right for the control you want to be to the right.

Comment: This works, but the StatusStrip property is named "LayoutStyle," not "Layout."

Answer (score 5):

First change AutoSize to false

`toolStripProgressBar.AutoSize = false;`

Then subscribe statusStrip's size changed event

`statusStrip1.SizeChanged += statusStrip1_SizeChanged;`

Finally change the bar's width in the event handler

```
private void statusStrip1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   toolStripProgressBar.Width = statusStrip1.Width - 95;
}
```